# material ui dropdown on enter click not selecting value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I am using [**this**](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) material ui dropdown... When I click on the dropdown and moving up and down with the arrow keys and press enter then the value doesn't get selected in the dropdown menu.

Here is the code for the dropdown

```
  handleChange(value) {
    this.props.fetchSubcategories(value)
  }

<Field
  name="boroughs"
  component={SelectField}
  type="text"
  hintText="Boroughs"
>
  {dasboardBoroughts.map((boroughts, i) => {
    return(<MenuItem onClick={() => this.handleChange(boroughts.name)} key={i} value={capitalize_Words(boroughts.name)} primaryText={capitalize_Words(boroughts.name)} />)
  })}
</Field>
```

Code for fetchSubcategories

```
export const fetchSubcategories = (data) => {
  const query = `{getSubcategories(category: "${data}") { foursquareData { categories { name }}}}`
  return fetch(HOSTNAME, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query })
  })
  .then((payload) => {
    return payload
  })
}
```

Comment: share your handleChange

Comment: updated... Just an api call there nothing else

Comment: Where is fetchNewSubCatergories and share it

Comment: `fetchNewSubCatergories` is just do an api call nothing else.

Comment: it return a promise, you need to wait for it.

Comment: If you want I can share an implementation here. And it would be great if you share fetchNewSubcategories api code

Comment: Thank you... Updated the question please check...

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for `async` operations in javascript. Your api resolves a promise upon success. You need to do this:

```
handleChange= value => {
 this.props.fetchSubcategories(value).then((res)=>{
  this.setState({
    menuvalue: //response value
  })
})
}
```

Later you can sue this state value in your in select value.

Comment: thanks for the help but there is nothing I can see related to solution in the above answer.

Comment: you need out select value it state : `value={capitalize_Words(this.state.boroughts.name)`